# Image resize using JAVAScript returning empty image

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying a write a JAVAScript which will take some base64 image and return a resized version of the image. I wrote this code. But it's returning an empty image. I searched a lot in google. But getting any solution. Here is the script.

Also, How can I resize the image with some maximum-width and maximum height?

```
function resizeImage(dataurl) {
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();


imageObj.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(imageObj, 100, 100);
};
imageObj.src = dataurl; 
var pngUrl = canvas.toDataURL();

return pngUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try change the method parameters:

```
 context.drawImage(imageObj,0 ,0, 100, 100);
```

because the first two parameters are the position and the third and fourth the size. 
Remember give the new canvas the same width and height of the modified image to avoid lost of the picture.

Answer (score 0):

```
context.drawImage(img,sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height);
```

If we just use first parameter, result should be padding 100 around the image, not blank.
There might be the browser cache for the image, here is the solution.

```
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = dataurl + (new Date().getIime());
imageObj.onload = function() {
   context.drawImage(imageObj, 100, 100);
};
```